# Expectation fails but test still passes

Tags: googletest, googlemock

When I have a mocked method whose calling expectations fail, the test is still passing. At first glance I thought there would be some kind of flag to control this behavior but I could not find one.

In case more context is required, this is happening to me with any kind of expectation, but as an example I have the following one, using a custom Matcher.

```cpp
// Expectation:

Foo expectedFoo;
Foo foo;
EXPECT_CALL(foo, GenerateEvent(1, FooEq(&expectedFoo)));

//Matcher:

MATCHER_P(FooEq, expected, "")
{
    return false;
}
```

if `foo.GenerateEvent(1, new Foo)` is called, the expectaction fails as expected, but the test still passes as shown below (had to hack the names due to privacy issues, hope I didn't mess the final result).

```
[ RUN      ] Test.FooTest
unknown file: error:
Unexpected mock function call - returning directly.
    Function call: GenerateEvent(1, 0D386FDC)
Google Mock tried the following 1 expectation, but it didn't match:

Foo.cpp(307): EXPECT_CALL(foo, GenerateEvent(1, FooEq(&expectedFoo)))...
  Expected arg #1: foo eq 012FF238
           Actual: 0D386FDC
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
[       OK ] Test.FooTest (15 ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StrictMock< Foo > foo;
```

Should cause the test to fail by throwing an exception when the unexpected call happens.  See [strict-mock](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md#mocking-a-normal-class-mockclass)